# Can someone help me with anugular universall? I am having a problem while running ssr?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

When I tried running @angular/universal in my ionic project there was a error
I had installed everything that was required for ng/universal
but still this was not working it resulted in the following results
These are the results of ng run:dev ssr

```
    at Object.pwa (C:\Users\Lucifer\Desktop\Zonion_Backup\dist\app\server\main.js:1:1109942)
    at C:\Users\Lucifer\Desktop\Zonion_Backup\dist\app\server\main.js:1:1108718
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at detectPlatforms (C:\Users\Lucifer\Desktop\Zonion_Backup\dist\app\server\main.js:1:1108692)
    at setupPlatforms (C:\Users\Lucifer\Desktop\Zonion_Backup\dist\app\server\main.js:1:1108534)
    at getPlatforms (C:\Users\Lucifer\Desktop\Zonion_Backup\dist\app\server\main.js:1:1108182)
    at isPlatform (C:\Users\Lucifer\Desktop\Zonion_Backup\dist\app\server\main.js:1:1108318)
    at Platform.is (C:\Users\Lucifer\Desktop\Zonion_Backup\dist\app\server\main.js:1:908156)
    at new AppComponent (C:\Users\Lucifer\Desktop\Zonion_Backup\dist\app\server\main.js:1:4035669)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.AppComponent_Factory [as factory] (C:\Users\Lucifer\Desktop\Zonion_Backup\dist\app\server\main.js:1:4038223)
```

Angular -version

```
Angular CLI: 11.2.9
Node: 14.15.5
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 11.2.10
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1102.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.1.1
@angular-devkit/core            11.2.9
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.2.9
@angular/animations             12.1.1
@angular/cli                    11.2.9
@angular/fire                   6.1.5
@angular/platform-server        11.2.14
@angular/service-worker         11.2.14
@nguniversal/builders           11.2.1
@nguniversal/express-engine     11.2.1
@schematics/angular             11.2.9
@schematics/update              0.1102.9
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.1.5
```

ioinc info

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.13.1 (C:\Users\Lucifer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.6.4
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 12.1.1
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 11.2.9
   @angular/cli                  : 11.2.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 3.1.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 11 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.3
   native-run  : 1.4.0

System:

   NodeJS : v14.15.5 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.14.11
   OS     : Windows 10
```